# Может ли Gitlab CI собирать с GitHub?

Tags: github, gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция, gitlab-ci

Собственно вопрос главный в заголовке.
Интересует возможность собирать в своем Gitlab CI проекты опенсорсные с github.  И если есть такая возможность, то подскажите как это реализуется.

Вариант перенести проект в Gitlab не подходит.

Comment: А вариант travis ci?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ да про это я знаю, интересует именно такая связка

Answer (score 2):

GitLab CI позволяет собирать только те проекты, которые находятся в самом GitLab, поскольку при работе он использует информацию о репозиториях, хранящуюся в самом GitLab.

Единственный вариант решения: [зеркалировать](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html) репозиторий с Github на репозиторий в GitLab, и уже для последнего настроить билды.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить в gitlab-ci.yml:

```
checkout_github:
  script: git clone https://github.com/<какой-то репзиторий>.git
```

Ну а дальше соответственно должны идти шаги сборки